# library (ecospat) problem with biomod2 version

Tags: r, biomod2

When I try to load 'ecospat' I find this problem:

```
> library(ecospat)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ecospat’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> namespace ‘biomod2’ 4.1-2 is being loaded, but < 4.0 is required

So I have tried to load a 'biomod2' 3.5.1 version, but I can't because it's not available for my version of R (4.2.1)

```
> install.packages("D:/Descargas/biomod2_3.5.1")

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/danie/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘D:/Descargas/biomod2_3.5.1’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Someone could help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the biomod2_3.5.1 package using the following code

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/biomod2/biomod2_3.5.1.tar.gz", 
                 repo=NULL, type="source")
```